# How to get system audio setting by using Java

Tags: java

I implemented a stand alone applet base  application for recording voice.I am able to know that microphone is attached or not but In case of user has set Internal  microphone and also attached head phone(external) with system then my application can't recognize that which microphone is selected and user start recording through head phone and voice couldn't be capture in this case.so i want to notify user through message please set external microphone setting in your system. 
So please help me how to know which microphone is using by system.
Here is the code to check that microphone is attached of not:-

```
public static boolean checkMicrophone()

{
    AudioFormat format=null;
            TargetDataLine tline;
    format = new AudioFormat( AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100.0F, 16, 2,4, 44100.0F, false);
    Mixer.Info[] allMixer = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
    boolean lineFound = false;
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format); 
    try{
                tline = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        lineFound=true;
            }catch(Exception e){

            }

    if(lineFound)

        return true;

    else
        return false;



}
```

Comment: ***ARRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRGHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH***.. Good, now I have your attention. Welcome to Stack overflow. When asking a question, please be sure you know *how* to ask a question. Include what you've tried, what you expected and what actually happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try this document, you will get it.....

```
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html
```

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/accessing.html

You can query the AudioSystem to learn what sorts of resources have been installed, and then you can obtain access to them. For example, an application program might start out by asking the AudioSystem class whether there is a mixer that has a certain configuration, such as one of the input or output configurations illustrated earlier in the discussion of lines. From the mixer, the program would then obtain data lines, and so on.

The following gets an array of the currently installed mixers on the system

```
AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()
```